# Using subprocess to run multiple commands in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
process1= r"C:\location\mybat.bat"
process2= r"C:\location\tools\gdal_translate  C:\temp\input.jpeg  C:\temp\output.pdf"

p1= subprocess.Popen([process1],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2= subprocess.Popen([process2],stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close()
output=p2.communicate()[0]
```

Now when I run both processes in the command prompt without using this script, it works fine but I want to automate it so it does it without any user interaction.

When I run this script it returns with :

```
  File "Myfile.py", line 52, in <module>
   p2= subprocess.Popen([process2],stdin=p1.stdout)
 File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
 File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in   _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am not well versed with subprocess, so I imagine there is an issue with my code in that regards. Any help would be great.

Comment: Would you please post the complete error log? Does "C:\location\tools\gdal_translate" means "C:\location\tools\gdal_translate.exe" or "C:\location\tools\gdal_translate.bat"?

Comment: Are you trying to pass process1's output to process2 ?

Comment: @ShanValleru That is essentially what I am attempting. I want to open up a command prompt, run the .bat, and then run the gdal_translate

Answer (score 0):

For `p2`, try this:

```
p2= subprocess.Popen(["C:\location\tools\gdal_translate", "C:\temp\input.jpeg", "C:\temp\output.pdf"],stdin=p1.stdout)
```

where I substitute `process2` with a list of strings.

Comment: Try repalce `gdal_translate` with `gdal_translate.exe`. It's possible subprocess cannot find the full executable name for you.

Comment: No, that did not seem to change anything either.

Comment: Can you make sure the for name of `C:\location\tools\gdal_translate` including extension?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal's is just to run multiple commands, use `subprocess.call` and should be as simple as this:

```
import subprocess
process1 = r"C:\location\mybat.bat"
process2 = r"C:\location\tools\gdal_translate"
p1 = subprocess.call([process1])
p2 = subprocess.call([process2, 'C:\temp\input.jpeg  C:\temp\output.pdf'])
```